# Eclipse in Ubuntu won't start, exits without any error code

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

When I start Eclipse, it will display the splash screen briefly and then exit without any error code.
I have searched in google, baidu and yahoo, haven't found an answer. Of course, haven't find an answer in stackoverflow either.

Someone said it can be solved by increasing the memory, I have tried, this method can't help me. My system is 64bit, and I have install 32bit jdk and 64bit jdk. Both of them can't solve the problem.

I have download some different type eclipse IDE from www.eclipse.org,**eclipse-cpp-indigo-incubation-linux-gtk-x86_64,eclipse-jee-indigo-linux-gtk-x86_64**, both of them have the same question.

Comment: have you installed eclipse through ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Are there any .log files in eclipse/configuration?  If so, paste the text here.

Comment: I installed eclipse by download eclipse from www.eclipse.org, just extract files to my workplace.

Comment: I can't find any .log files in eclipse/configuration, when I run eclipse, first appear splash window, after a short time, it will exit without any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

"I installed eclipse by download eclipse from www.eclipse.org, just extract files to my workplace."...i am not sure what the issue is ,but this happened to me too.. when i tried installing offline by just downloading and extracting eclipse,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_I_unzipped_Eclipse%2C_but_it_won%27t_start._Why%3F

I later re-installed through ubuntu software center works like a charm.I would recommend you to install through either 1 of these ways

1.through terminal

`sudo apt-get install eclipse`

2.through synaptic package manager

3.through software center

coz,that way the configurations are checked and the latest version of eclipse is installed,later you may add your plugins following steps on the eclipse site :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for these configurations.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE
- http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-and-setup-eclipse-with-suns-java.html

Comment: thanks for your answer.I have added essential environment variables, such as $JAVA_HOME, ＄JRE＿HOME， and added $JAVA_HOME to $PATH but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such a problem when trying to run eclipse on a server install. Eclipse would start to run and then silently exit. I installed eclipse from the tarball available for direct download, NOT via apt-get or synaptics, FYI. My problem turned out to be missing GTK libs - since it is a server OS, most of the graphics related stuff is not installed by default. "aptitude install libgtk2.0-0" solved my problem.